# yocto how to override SRCREV in a recipe

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

In one of the kernel recipes the revision is specified:

```
   SRC_URI = "${KERNEL_SRC};branch=${SRCBRANCH}"
   SRCREV = "dd055f07f727803a7542541f560f69daed8209f4"
   LINUX_VERSION = "5.15.60"
```

Is it possible to override the SRCREV in another layer?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, create bbappend for the recipe.

Comment: I understand if the SRCREV is defined as SRCREV ?= "dd055f07f727803a7542541f560f69daed8209f4" it can be overridden with bbapend. But it is defined as SRCREV = "dd055f07f727803a7542541f560f69daed8209f4" will it still work? So basically the original recipe is always processed before any append file? Thanks!

Comment: bbappend overrides the original recipe.